# Writing to a CSV file in Python

Tags: python, csv

I'm totally new to Python, but am pretty well-versed in other languages so I have at least some idea of what's going on. I did not write this code, but I am trying to make it work for my purposes.

I'm using an [API](https://github.com/BurntSushi/nflgame) to retrieve statistics about every play in the NFL from last season. I am trying to write this information to a CSV file, and so far, it's writing the headers to the file and not the actual data.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

```
import csv 
import nflgame 

games = nflgame.games_gen(2013, kind='REG') 
plays = nflgame.combine_plays(games) 
headers = [] 
for statId, info in nflgame.statmap.idmap.iteritems(): 
    headers += info['fields'] 
    headers.sort() 
    headers = ['gsis_id', 'drive_id', 'play_id', 'desc'] + headers 
    writer = csv.DictWriter(open('2013_regular_plays.csv', 'w+'), fieldnames=headers) 
    writer.writerow({k: k for k in headers}) 
    for p in plays: 
        row = {k: getattr(p, k, 0) for k in headers} 
        row['gsis_id'] = p.drive.game.eid 
        row['drive_id'] = p.drive_num 
        row['play_id'] = p.playid 
        row['desc'] = p.desc 
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: @alfasin: note the definition of the `writer`: it knows how to interpret field names.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like it should mostly work.

The only detail which is wrong [compared to the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.writer) is that the file should be open in binary mode (`w+b`).

Also, it is important that the file be closed before you can have a look at it:

```
with open('2013_regular_plays.csv', 'w+b') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.DictWriter(csv_file, fieldnames=headers)
    …
```

will automatically close the file after the `with` block (and the file mode could be more simply `wb`, if the file is not read inside this block). If you look at the file before it is closed, its contents might still reside in RAM instead of on the disk.

**PS**: As DSM pointed out, each iteration `for statId, info in…` *empties the CSV file* when you open it with the `w+` (or `w+b`) mode. If the last iteration has no plays, then the file end up being empty (with headers only). You typically want to open the CSV file *before* the loop (maybe even simply with the `wb` mode).

Comment: +1 it's worth mentioning that `b` mode is necessary only in python 2.

Comment: @DSM: Yep, it will. `w+` implies that the file will also be opened for *reading* too (as opposed to `w`, which opens it for writing only: reading causes "IOError: File not open for reading").

Comment: @alfasin: Yes, with `newline=''` having to be added to `open()` in Python 3 (https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/csv.html#csv.reader).

Comment: .. but this is happening *inside a loop*.  Say, for example, that `plays` isn't a list but something which can be exhausted on the first pass.  Then the `for p in plays:` loop won't fire afterward, and all that the OP would see at the end would be the header written on the last loop, because using `w` clobbered everything before.